# Subsequent ajax calls in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to make subsequent ajax calls in angularJs inside a service.

I've tried with something like this:

```
var requests = [
    {'url': 'call1'},
    {'url': 'call2'},
    {'url': 'call3'}
];

return $q.all([
    $http({
        url: requests[0],
        method: "POST"
    }).then( /*callback*/ ),
    $http({
        url: requests[1],
        method: "POST"
    }).then( /*callback*/ )
]);
```

But this make alla ajax in parallel. I need a way to make this calls subsequent, so after first end, it calls second....

Comment: Do subsequent calls need to use info from the responses to previous calls, or are you just giving the server time to complete a series steps one at a time?

Comment: If one request fails, do you want abort all subsequent requests?

Answer (score 2):

You can chain promises:

```
  var requests =[{'url':'index.html'},
               {'url':'index.html'},
               {'url':'index.html'}];

function makeCall(n) {
  return $http({url:requests[n].url+"?n="+n,method:"GET"}).then(function(r) {
     if (n+1<requests.length) return makeCall(n+1);
  });
}
   makeCall(0);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1HdYUtHKe8WXAFBBq8HE?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You could use [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries):

```
var requests = ['call1', 'call2', 'call3'];

function iterator(request, done) {
    $http({
        url: request,
        method: "POST"
    }).then(done);
};

async.eachSeries(
    requests,
    iterator,
    function (err) {
        // Done
    }
);
```

From the [readme](https://github.com/caolan/async):

> **eachSeries(arr, iterator, callback)**
>   The same as each only the iterator is applied to each item in the array in series. The next iterator is only called once the current one has completed processing. This means the iterator functions will complete in order.
>
> - `arr` - An array to iterate over.
> - `iterator(item, callback)` - A function to apply to each item in the array. The iterator is passed a `callback(err)` which must be called once it has completed. If no error has occured, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument.
> - `callback(err)` - A callback which is called after all the iterator functions have finished, or an error has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call another $http call in the "then" callback, returning the return value of $http

```
$http({...})
.then(function() {
  return $http({...});
 })
.then(function() {
  return $http({...});
});
```

This works because each call to $http returns a promise. If you return a promise in the "then" success callback, then the next "then" callback in the chain will be deferred until that promise is resolved, which will be when the ajax call completes.

Edit: In response to the comment, you can loop over an array of requests:

```
var requests = [
   {'url':'call1','method':'get'},
   {'url':'call2','method':'get'},
   {'url':'call3','method':'get'}
];

var promise = null;
angular.forEach(requests, function(details) {
  promise = $q.when(promise).then(function() {
    return $http(details);
  });
});
```

As in the Plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/RSMN8WuPOpvdCujtrrZZ?p=preview . The `$q.when` is just for the first value of the loop, when `promise` is set to `null`, so it has a `then` callback that is called immediately.

Comment: yes, but if I have a lot of calls this become more verbose code. I'd like a simple solution as loop over each url in my array and call one at a time

Comment: I've added a section that shows how this can be used in a loop.

Comment: Won't this loop all the way through without blocking? The asker wants to execute the requests in series.

Comment: None of the solutions with $http should 'block', as they are all asynchronous. However, if you are asking whether all the requests will run at the same time, instead of sequentially, then no, that shouldn't happen. The only promise that calls the `then` callback immediately is the first one. The others will all wait until the call to `$http` has completed. I've made a [modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WXjDcGYniSPZSRZNyVF8?p=preview) with an extra $timeout between http calls that shows this.